# Get the previous row end date as the next row start date in POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql, lag, lead

I have a table here with *hire_date* and *effectivity_date* of each employee which will be updated every time. I would like to get the previous row effectivity date as the next row *start_date*, and the *end_date* of the previous date will be minus 1 to avoid overlapping. Also, I want the last record's *end_date* to be '2030-12-31' as the default value and the **Hire Date** as the *start_date* of the first record. Please help me with this one.

**Current table:**
[image]

**Expected Output:**
[image]

Comment: By the tags I see you already identified the right window functions. Can you share with us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I found some duplicates in your original table, like `Ross` and `Chandler` have 2 entries with exactly the same dataset. If that is a copy/paste error, then I reproduced your case with:

```
create table testdt(name varchar, hire_dt date, eff_dt date);


insert into testdt values('Rachel','2021-03-29','2021-03-29');
insert into testdt values('Rachel','2021-03-29','2021-05-14');
insert into testdt values('Ross','2021-06-18','2021-06-18');
insert into testdt values('Monica','2021-07-21','2021-07-21');
insert into testdt values('Chandler','2021-04-12','2021-04-12');
insert into testdt values('Judy','2021-04-26','2021-04-26');
insert into testdt values('Judy','2021-04-26','2021-05-10');
insert into testdt values('Judy','2021-04-26','2021-07-01');
```

Now, correctly as your tag mention, you need to use the `LAG` and `LEAD` function which will get columns from the previous and next row accordingly.

If you run on the above `testdt` table the following SQL, you'll get the previous and next `eff_dt`. Please note I use the `ctid` as ordering column

```
select *, 
    ctid, 
    lead(eff_dt) over (partition by name order by ctid) as lead_eff_dt,
    lag(eff_dt) over (partition by name order by ctid) as lag_eff_dt
from testdt tst order by ctid
```

The result is the following

```
   name   |  hire_dt   |   eff_dt   | ctid  | lead_eff_dt | lag_eff_dt 
----------+------------+------------+-------+-------------+------------
 Rachel   | 2021-03-29 | 2021-03-29 | (0,1) | 2021-05-14  | 
 Rachel   | 2021-03-29 | 2021-05-14 | (0,2) |             | 2021-03-29
 Ross     | 2021-06-18 | 2021-06-18 | (0,3) |             | 
 Monica   | 2021-07-21 | 2021-07-21 | (0,4) |             | 
 Chandler | 2021-04-12 | 2021-04-12 | (0,5) |             | 
 Judy     | 2021-04-26 | 2021-04-26 | (0,6) | 2021-05-10  | 
 Judy     | 2021-04-26 | 2021-05-10 | (0,7) | 2021-07-01  | 2021-04-26
 Judy     | 2021-04-26 | 2021-07-01 | (0,8) |             | 2021-05-10
```

Now we can apply your logic:
For the **START_DATE**
if it's the first row (`lag_eff_dt` is `null`) then we use the `hire_dt`, otherwise, if there is a following row (`lead_eff_dt` is not `null`) then we take the the following `eff_dt`. If it's the last row, we take `eff_dt`.

For the **END_DATE**
We just need to take `2021-12-31` if there is no following record (`lead_eff_dt` is `null`), we take one day off from the next `eff_dt` otherwise

The following query should do

```
with first_sel as(
select *, 
    ctid, 
    lead(eff_dt) over (partition by name order by ctid) as lead_eff_dt,
    lag(eff_dt) over (partition by name order by ctid) as lag_eff_dt
from testdt tst order by ctid)
select 
    name, 
    case when lag_eff_dt is null
        then hire_dt
        else
            case when lead_eff_dt is not null
                then (lead_eff_dt)::date
                else eff_dt 
        end
        end as start,
    coalesce((lead_eff_dt - INTERVAL '1 DAY')::date, '2021-12-31'::date) as end
    

from first_sel;
```

With the result being

```
   name   |   start    |    end     
----------+------------+------------
 Rachel   | 2021-03-29 | 2021-05-13
 Rachel   | 2021-05-14 | 2021-12-31
 Ross     | 2021-06-18 | 2021-12-31
 Monica   | 2021-07-21 | 2021-12-31
 Chandler | 2021-04-12 | 2021-12-31
 Judy     | 2021-04-26 | 2021-05-09
 Judy     | 2021-07-01 | 2021-06-30
 Judy     | 2021-07-01 | 2021-12-31
(8 rows)
```

Comment: Wow! This is great. Another thing, I would like to new column **supervisor**, how could I implement that? I added supervisor in Select but it gets the hire_date as the startDate when assigned to a new supervisor when it should be the latest effectivity date.

Comment: You need to provide a concrete example for this, otherwise we can't help

Comment: Here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4D8PbXMJR9tjFUiAVPZhDc/0

Judy's second record -- start date is incorrect, should be 2021-05-10